# Alternatives to Bottling Wands

Tags: bottling, siphon

Not having kegged, I don't mind what some people call the 'hell' of bottling.  However, after bottling a 10% BGSA last night where I used a 2 quart starter (leading to a massive yeast cake) and whole leaf hops (which made it into the primary), a clogged/slow-flowing autosiphon, a slow-flowing bottle wand, all leading up to a 3+ hour bottling session, I have a new maxim and a question:

Maxim:  Always strain out whole hops or use a muslin bag.
Question:  Are there any lowish-cost alternatives to a bottling wand?

There's a good chance next time I'll just break out my march pump instead of the siphon next time as well, though I haven't had a problem in the past...

Comment: I'm confused.  Was the problem that the inlet to your autosiphon and the tip of your wand got plugged up? (couldn't think of a less dirty way to ask that)

Comment: <snicker>  wait, wait, the "what" of my "what"????  It was both actually.  A simple solution is to not use whole leaf hops or strain them out prior to fermentation, but I was looking to see if there was a different device to use as opposed to the wand.

Comment: I always transfer from the secondary fermenter onto the bottling sugar and then into bottles. When I dry hopped my last batch that worked nicely. Leaving all the hops in the secondary and making for a very easy bottling.

Answer (score 2):

I use a bucket with a spigot on the bottom for bottling.  It was quite easy, even for a newbie like me.

Comment: you should attach a bottling wand to that so it fills the bottles from the bottom up to minimize oxidation.  Your beer can get a cardboardy taste if exposed to too much oxygen, which can happen only when using the spigot on the bottling bucket.

Comment: @Pietro Took your advice for my most recent batch.  Filling went nice and easy.  I'm looking forward to giving it a taste after a week or two.

Answer (score 0):

my brew set up doesn't have a valve at the bottom of my brew kettle yet and over the course of quite a few sessions (with an auto-siphon) I have found that a simple basket strainer with a handle at the bottom of the siphon tube (following the liquid level down) works awesome! Every time the siphon tube would get clogged and it is so frustrating, so I feel your pain. GOOD LUCK!